# Simple form error messages moving input boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm having an issue with the way that error messages are formatted on my "registration" form, using the simple_form gem. 
[This is what my registration form looks like when handling errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt8HU.png)

I want the error messages to appear below the input boxes, and I don't want the alignment of the input boxes to change when incorrect input is submitted. The input and error messages are structured as seen below:

```
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification input_html: { class: 'error' } %>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Email', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
          <%= f.input :user_name, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'User Name', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
          <%= f.input :password, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Password', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
          <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Confirm Password', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
```

Is there something I can adjust in my css to make the error messages appear in the center below the input boxes? I have tried messing around with the margins, but when I do, the input boxes change alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was pretty simple. Just had to edit the CSS as follows:

```
.error {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```